# How to get a custom Status code to work? Or How to solve this problem using a built in http status code?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, session, authentication, iis-7

I have an asp.net mvc 3 site running locally and everything works fine. I upload it to my shared hosting site and my code that should watch for session timeouts does not work.

I have this in my web.config

```
 <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="/Account"
                      protection="All"
                      name=".MySite"
                      path="/"
                      requireSSL="false"
                      slidingExpiration="true"
                      defaultUrl="default.aspx"
                      cookieless="UseDeviceProfile"
                      enableCrossAppRedirects="false"
                       timeout="1"
                       />
    </authentication>
```

So  I have this in my web.config to do the timeout stuff. I set to timeout after 1 min to do the testing when they are logged into their account and leave or do not do anything.

So now this would all work if 90% of my site was not AJAX. When a user times out and does an AJAX request it goes to my account controller index method(what is the login page) but since it is an AJAX request it downloads the entire login page and throws it say in the Jquery Tab trying to load up.

So I have a tab that all of sudden renders the login page and it looks awful and confuses the users.

So that's why I came up with this solution.

Once the redirect happens in the forms authentication it goes to the Index method

```
 [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        string returnUrl = HttpContext.ApplicationInstance.Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"];

        // check to see if the user got redirected. Only 2 possibilities session timed out or they where not authenticated in the first place.
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
        {
            Response.StatusCode = 900;
        }

        return View();
    }
```

Then in my ajax setup I watch for this status code.

```
   statusCode:
            {
                900: function ()
                {
                    window.location = "/Account?SessionTimeOut=Yes";
                }
            }
        });
```

Then as you can see I redirect to the login page and display a message.

```
var sessionTimeOut = $.url().param("SessionTimeOut");

if (sessionTimeOut == "Yes") 
{
      alert("timeout");
}
```

Like I said this works on local host. I am using a custom status code instead of 401 because it prompts a dialog box asking the user to re-authenticate themselves. I am using openId so they have no password. So this dialog would confuse the user.

When I upload to the server I had to add this

```
  <httpErrors>
      <error statusCode="900" subStatusCode="-1" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/Account" responseMode="Redirect" />
  </httpErrors>
```

Since what I was finding if someone typed in a url to an authenticated page when they where not authenticated(say http:/mysite.com/controller/authenticationNeededPage)

It would put that 900 status code and IIS 7.5 I guess did not know what to do with this custom status code as it had no clue where to redirect.

when a user times out though while on my live site it's like the 900 code gets ignored. I am watching the ajax request that loads up a tab and it should have 900 status code but it returns 302 redirect.

So then my jquery status code never finds it and the login page loads up in the tab and looks horrible. I have no clue why it does not send back my 900 status code like it does on local host.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a custom HTTP header instead of inventing some inexistent in the HTTP specification status codes that might not be served by IIS.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    string returnUrl = HttpContext.ApplicationInstance.Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"];

    // check to see if the user got redirected. Only 2 possibilities session timed out or they where not authenticated in the first place.
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
    {
        Response.AppendHeader("X-LOGIN-PAGE", "true");
    }
    return View();
}
```

and now on your client side:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    complete: function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
        if (jqXHR.getResponseHeader('X-LOGIN-PAGE') === 'true') {
             // We have gone through the Login method => the session 
             // might have expired
             window.location = "/Account?SessionTimeOut=Yes";
        };
    }
});
```

Comment: hmm I will try that but my test on local host shows that they would still see the tab render all nasty then it does the redirect. It is only for like a second or 2 till the redirect happens but still don't like how it flashes like that. Is there away to have this check move up (I still want it a global solution like how had above or how I had with the status codes)